# Odds of two specific people getting into the same school?

Tags: probability

Say for example, two friends want to go to the same school. 15,000 people apply, and only a total of 400 are accepted. What is the percent chance that these two friends get accepted?

Comment: Can you show your effort on this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at both links [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and for formatting [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: $P(x)=\frac{400}{15000}.\frac{399}{14999}$

Answer (score 1):

*Solution.* Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ denote the two friends in question and denote $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be the events that $F_1$ is selected and $F_2$ is selected respectively then the probability of interest namely $\mathbf{P}(A_1\cap A_2)$ is as follows.
$$\mathbf{P}(A_1\cap A_2) = \frac{\binom{14998}{398}}{\binom{15000}{400}}$$

Sadly your earlier answer is not correct.